# Looking for a jquery plugin that will degrade an HTML5 audio tag gracefully

Tags: jquery, html

Is there such a thing? The plugin would make an HTML5 audio tag work (render a functional audio player) in browsers that don't support the tag or support it only partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [MediaElementJS](http://www.mediaelementjs.com). It's not strictly jQuery, but it works well.